# Javascript: grab object in array based on subobject value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

If I have this object:

```
DropIds = [
  {
    "studentId": 5,
    "dropboxItems": [
        {
            "dropBoxId": 230,
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "studentId": 4,
    "dropboxItems": [
        {
            "dropBoxId": 585,
        },
        {
            "dropBoxId": 586,
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I try to run this code:

```
var result = $.grep(DropIds, function(e){
    return e.dropboxItems[0].dropBoxId == 585;
});
```

it will return a result, however if I change it from 585 to 586 the result is empty.

http://jsfiddle.net/tdb70f50/1/

So it looks like my code will only check the first object in the array.

How can I grab the object when there is more than one dropBoxId?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to also loop through the items of `dropboxItems` rather than just look at the first item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check all the items in the array, not just the `0` index, you can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var result = DropIds.filter(function(item) {
    return item.dropboxItems.filter(function(box) {
        return box.dropBoxId == 586
    }).length
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/56h7daod/

Comment: You could replace the inner `.filter()` with [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (and therefore remove the `.length`). This will only check box items until it finds the first match. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chd3zayh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are only testing the first element (zero as index);

```
return e.dropboxItems[0].dropBoxId == 585;
```

you have to loop inside elements testing each object;

```
var result = $.grep(DropIds, function(e){
    if(!e.dropboxItems) return false;

    for(var i = 0; i < e.dropboxItems.length; i++) {
        if(e.dropboxItems[i].dropBoxId == 586) return true
    }

    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tdb70f50/2/

Answer (score 0):

In conjunction with the answers already provided, you can make good use of mapping and reducing to extract an array of nested `dropBoxItems` and then perform a search for a given `dropBoxId`, ie:

```
function getByDropBoxId(id, dropId) {
  return dropId
    // Pluck the nested arrays into a 2d array
    .map(function (dropId) {
      return dropId.dropboxItems;
    })
    // flatten / reduce them to a single array.
    .reduce(function (soFar, dropBoxItems) {
      return soFar.concat(dropBoxItems);
    }, [])
    // filter out the ones you are looking for and return the first.
    .filter(function(dropBoxItem) {
      return dropBoxItem.dropBoxId === id; 
    })[0];
};
```